# Git is fast without vendors installed, but terribly slow after composer install

Tags: eclipse, git, composer-php, development-environment, samba

After cloning a Git repo switching/branching is really fast, but this performance decreases when we install the vendors using `composer install`.

The environment is a mounted samba share from the Debian development server. We're developing in Windows 8.1 using Eclipse PDT with Egit for version control. The network speed is fine, there is a gbit network everywhere.

Where a commit / switch took 10 seconds before `composer install` it takes 3-5 minutes afterwards. Ofcourse it is possible to use git from the CLI directly, but then we still have to refresh the working copy in Eclipse every time.

Does the vendor folder (which ofcourse isn't under version control) really affect the performance tat much? The vendor folder is in `.gitignore` but is there another way to let Egit ignore the vendor folder?

Comment: Just to clarify... when you run git commands from the command line they are fast? Is it only Eclipse that is slow?

Comment: You are probably better off using git NOT from the eclipse. Get a SourceTree or something.

Comment: Yes I can make use of another Git tool in Windows, but then I still have to refresh the working copy in Eclipse. Why is Eclipse +git only dead slow when all vendor folders are installed?